# how to divide a huge list in equal blocks and apply conditions to those blocks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, python-2.7

There are two parts

## Part 1

I have list which contain number (both +ve and -ve).

These numbers are basically there on the basis of 15 min time block, so there are 96 blocks in a day and 35040 blocks in a year.

I have one year of data so there are 35040 values in that list. I want to divide that list day wise (in 96 blocks). I know how to divide a list using yield function but I don't know how to access those list and do my calculations. So part one is to divide that list into 96 blocks.

## Part 2

Suppose if I'm counting the number of violations block wise then I want my counter reset at 97<sup>th</sup> block, means everyday there will be a new counter.

### My code to divide the list:

```
[lst[i:i + 96] for i in range(0, len(lst), 96)]
```

I don't know how to reset the counter at every 97<sup>th</sup> block in a list. Basically, I want to extract the data day wise and 96 values stands for 1 day and there are 35040 values, so there will be 365 days. So please help to extract data day wise and reset the counter everyday.

Expected output:

```
time interval(15min) days     dev      counter
 1                             -1       
 2                             -2 
 3                             -54
 4                             -21
 5                             -42
 6                             -11
 7                             -32         1
 .                              .
 .                              . 
 .                              31         13 
 96                    1        32     (counter reset)
 97                             84          
 98                             32  
 99                             12
 100                            11
 101                             1
 102                             3 
 103                            23          1
 .                                   
 191                                        12
 192                   2        -43     (counter reset)
 ...
 35040                 365      -54
```

my code for the counter:

```
for each in dev:

    if each > 0:
        minus_counter = 0
        plus_counter += 1

        if plus_counter == 7:
            count = answer_counter
            row_counter = answer_counter
            counts.append(count)
            plus_counter = 0
            answer_counter += 1

        else:
            counts.append(0)

    elif each < 0:
        plus_counter = 0
        minus_counter += 1

        if minus_counter == 7:
            count = answer_counter
            row_counter = answer_counter
            counts.append(count)
            minus_counter = 0
            answer_counter += 1
        else:
            counts.append(0)

    row_counter += 1
```

this ll count the number of 7 consecutive -ve or +ve dev.
Rest day reset part  I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Present the expected result

Comment: Try it using counter and if condition

Comment: what is  `violation`?

Comment: How does your list look like?

Comment: I edited my question and added the expected  result and my attempt

Answer (score 0):

After partitioning your data, evaluate day wise - and enumerate over the partitions and get the number of the day from the enumeration.

Example:

- creates negative/positive numbers and evaluate them
- count how many are positive/negative/magnitude over 5

---

```
import random

data = [random.randint(-5,5)/.7 for _ in range(28)]

# partition into days with 4 datapoints per day
days = [ data[i:i+4] for i in range(0,28,4)]

# iterate over day data - no need to reset counters
# create tuples for each day, counting whatever we want)
# violations could be, f.e. magnitude > 5
count_em = [ (sum(v < 0 for v in d), sum(v >= 0 for v in d), 
              sum(abs(v) > 5 for v in d)) for d in days ]


# zip the data and the countings together, enumerate and output them
for day,(d,cnt) in enumerate(zip(days,count_em),1):
    print("day:",day, d)
    print("negative: {}  positive/zero: {}  magnitude > 5: {}\n".format(*cnt))

# total magnitudes > 5: 
# print ( sum( c[2] for c in count_em))
```

Output:

```
day: 1 [5.714285714285714, 5.714285714285714, -1.4285714285714286, -5.714285714285714]
negative: 2  positive/zero: 2  magnitude > 5: 3

day: 2 [0.0, 7.142857142857143, 2.857142857142857, -4.285714285714286]
negative: 1  positive/zero: 3  magnitude > 5: 1

day: 3 [7.142857142857143, -7.142857142857143, 5.714285714285714, 0.0]
negative: 1  positive/zero: 3  magnitude > 5: 3

day: 4 [-5.714285714285714, 5.714285714285714, 0.0, 2.857142857142857]
negative: 1  positive/zero: 3  magnitude > 5: 2

day: 5 [-4.285714285714286, -1.4285714285714286, -1.4285714285714286, 1.4285714285714286]
negative: 3  positive/zero: 1  magnitude > 5: 0

day: 6 [4.285714285714286, 0.0, -2.857142857142857, -1.4285714285714286]
negative: 2  positive/zero: 2  magnitude > 5: 0

day: 7 [1.4285714285714286, 4.285714285714286, -2.857142857142857, -4.285714285714286]
negative: 2  positive/zero: 2  magnitude > 5: 0
```